# how to handle Rest template api error response and convert to type safe Json?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, kotlin

i am new to spring boot, i want to handle error response in rest template as type safe way.

I've already tried exception handling with rest template, but it doesn't resolve my problem. or maybe i don't know how to properly use it.

`val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
 restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, payload, UserResponse::class.java) // getting error here because of error response`

//what i actually want is something like this

`val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
restTemplate.setSuccessEntity(UserResponse::class.java)
restTemplate.setErrorEntity(ErrorResponse::class.java)
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, payload)`

and the expected response would be like this

`{
"error":{} // null or ErrorResponse Entity object if there is an error
"success":{} // null or UserResponse Entity object if there is an error
}`

Comment: What should be the content of `error` in response? Do you want to contain error from external api?

Comment: yes, for example if external API give some json error response i want it to be converted to json using my defined ErrorResonse.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Define your custom `RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler`

```java
class MyRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler : ResponseErrorHandler {
 override fun hasError(response: ClientHttpResponse): Boolean {
   return response.statusCode.is4xxClientError || response.statusCode.is5xxServerError //or sth else depending on your case
 }
 override fun handleError(response: ClientHttpResponse) {
   val msg = response.body.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
   throw MyExternalApiException(msg)
 }
}
```

`MyExternalApiException` could be defined like:

```java
class MyExternalApiError(msg: String) : RuntimeException(msg)
```

2. Make it a `Bean`

```java
@Bean
fun responseErrorHandler(): ResponseErrorHandler {
  return MyRestTemplateResponseErrorHandler()
}
```

3. Use it to create `RestTemplate Bean` with `RestTemplateBuilder`

```java
@Bean
fun restTemplate(restTemplateBuilder: RestTemplateBuilder,
                     responseErrorHandler: ResponseErrorHandler): RestTemplate {
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .errorHandler(responseErrorHandler)
                .build()
}
```

4. Now that you have error handler working correctly and you throw `MyExternalApiException` when external api fails you can create `ControllerAdvice` to return special entity when this exception occurs. Your controller will return `ErrorResponse` with the message you obtained from failed external api request.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
class ApiErrorHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(value = [MyExternalApiException::class])
  fun handleExternalApiException(e: MyExternalApiException): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(ErrorResponse(e.message
                        ?: "External api error"))
    }

 data class ErrorResponse(val message: String)
```

In case of successful request just return normally with your successful entity.
If you want to have both `error` and `success` fields in all responses, just set one of those fields. `error` in `ApiErrorHandler` and `success` after `restTemplate.exchange()`.

If you want that external error to be mapped to your class, not a string, you can use jacksons object mapper or other library.

Comment: very elegant answer, this does answer my question, but unfortunately i cant upvote due to low points

Comment: You can just accept as an answer with a "tick". Thanks in advance